# Docker не видит папку с статическим контентом (images)

Tags: java, spring, docker, docker-compose

Я делаю проект с использованием Spring Boot и Maven. В моем проекте есть функционал по загрузке фотографий на сервер (аватарок). Они загружаются в папку со статическим контентом (static) в папку images (полный путь от корня src/main/resources/static/images), также для "раздачи" статического контента у меня есть код, который "раздает" статический контент (чтобы не перезагружать сервер для обновления фотографий).

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${upload.resources-path}")
    private String uploadPath;

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
            .addResourceHandler("/images/**")
            .addResourceLocations("file:" + uploadPath + "/");
    }
}

* Переменная uploadPath = "src\main\resources\static\images"
```

Сам функционал работает на локальном компьютере и при попытке установить это всё на Docker, приложение перестает видеть папку images и подгрузка фотографий прекращается. Самая картинка сохраняется не в виде массива `byte[]`, а просто как цельная картинка и затем с HTML-страницы я просто обращаюсь к нужному адресу до аватарки пользователя (к примеру, `http://localhost:8080/images/anon.jpg`). Интересный момент в том, что JS и CSS из этой папки он подгружает. А при оббращении к images возникает что-то такое `GET http://localhost:8080/images/anon.jpg 404`

В целом, больше никаких настроек по поводу статического контента нет, кроме класса `MvcConfig` и перемнной `uploadPath`. Если нужны какие-то ещё файла или пояснения спрашивайте.

Ниже привёл файл docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:   db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USERNAME: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 1234
      POSTGRES_DB: dexterity

  compileta:
    container_name: compileta
    image: compileta
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      SERVER_PORT: 8081

  app:
    build: .
    container_name: dexterity
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    command: java -jar dexterity.jar --spring.profiles.active=dev
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/dexterity
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: postgres
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: 1234
      COMPILETA_COMPILEURL: http://compileta:8081/compile
      COMPILETA_COMPILALLURL: http://compileta:8081/compile_all
    links:
      - db
      - compileta
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут проблема совсем не в докере, а в том, что ваш код написан непереносимым образом.

А именно он будет работать только при запуске его из корневой директории проекта (что и делает IDE). Если вы запустите приложение на хосте из другого каталога, то приложение не найдет папку `src\main\resources\static\images` точно также как и сейчас оно не находит ее в докере.

Другими словами код рассчитывает, что в текущей директории будет существовать директория `src`, в ней `main` и т.д., а в при запуске в докер это не так. Там существует только jar файл с приложением. Само приложение пробует использовать несуществующую директорию.

Чтоб исправить эту проблему, вам нужно использовать какую-то директорию, которая существует в докер контейнер. Создайте параметр конфигурации, который будет определять, где нужно хранить загруженные файлы, и задавайте его в конфигурации docker-compose.

Саму директорию нужно через volume присоединить к контейнеру (если вам нужно данные сохранять при перезапуске приложения), либо нужно создать ее при сборке образа, либо само приложение при старте должно ее создавать.

Это может быть абсолютно произвольный путь в контейнере. Например `/avatars`. Если без volume, то в `Dockerfile` нужно добавить команду создания директории:

```
...
RUN mkdir /avatars
...
```

С volume это может так:

```
  app:
    container_name: dexterity
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    command: java -jar --spring.profiles.active=dev dexterity.jar --upload.resources-path=/avatars
    volumes:
      - /some/path/on/host/avatars:/avatars
```

это присоединит папку с хоста `/some/path/on/host/avatar` в контейнер как `/avatars` и задаст параметр `upload.resources-path`.

Еще одни момент - это использование `src/main/resources` для хранения динамических данных. Это опять же непереносимо. Там должны быть только статические ресурсы. Все динамическое должно быть либо в БД либо в файловой системе.

Comment: Ну как то же до неё путь нужно указывать, можешь написать какие то примеры таких путей? В случае если volume использовать и в случае, если не использовать

Comment: добавил про папки